# Scala calculating two values in a map

Tags: scala

I have the following map `Map(FULL -> 3854.0, REMAINING -> 3769.0)`
I would like to compute the two values such that the (FULL/REMAINING)*100
Is there an good way to do this?  I tried `m.foldLeft(0)(_/_._2)` but the compilier is complaining about a type mismatch between float and Int?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fix the type mismatch by specifying `0.0` as the first argument to `foldLeft`, but that won't make your code right. It will then compute `0.0/3854.0/3769.0` which equals `0.0`.

In fact, `Map(FULL -> 3854.0, REMAINING -> 3769.0)` is not guaranteed to be ordered, so I'm pretty sure the best you can do is `m('FULL') / m('REMAINING')`.

Perhaps you want to create a `case class` for this instead, in which case you could just say `m.full/m.remaining` or even make a method to compute that automatically.

Answer (score 1):

With a Map, there is no guarantee, that the two value are really present. So you may want to create a class for that, as Ken Bloom already suggested, or do it with the `get` method of `Map`, which returns an `Option[B]`:

```
val resOpt = for {
  full <- m.get("FULL")
  remainig <- m.get("REMAINING")
} yield (full / remaining) * 100

resOpt.getOrElse(someDefaultValue)
```

This way you avoid nasty runtime errors.